# Python - Numpy matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, python-2.7, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to optimize (memorywise the multiplication of X and its transpose X'

Does anyone know if numpys matrix multiplication takes into consideration that X' is just the transpose of X. What I mean is that if it detects this and therfore does not create the object X' but just works on the cols/rows of X to produce the product? Thank you for any help on this!

J.

Comment: look in to numpy views. http://scipy-lectures.github.com/ might be a good reference.

Comment: Depending on the application, you may also be able to get by with `numpy.cov(X)`, which I assume is well-optimized, instead of computing `XX'` explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In numpy convention, the transpose of `X` is represented by`X.T` and you're in luck, `X.T` is just a view of the original array `X`, meaning that no copy is done.